# Bixby : Implement Booking service in our capsule

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

We are planning to implement a booking service for our capsule.
I got a link that supports credit card payment.
link: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.payments.

According to the link, Our region is not supported by Samsung Payment Services (SPS). So, which payment method we can use to implement booking service in our capsule for Bixby.

And is there any capsule example which supports the booking service.

Any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation, SPS is a limited feature and you should contact the Samsung Developer Relations (email is on the page) support directly for help:

> Note Support for Samsung Payment Services is currently limited to
>   specific developers. If you are interested in integrating Samsung
>   Payment in your capsule, reach out to the Samsung Developer Relations
>   team for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If your region is not currently supported by SPS, or you need to communicate with a different payment provider, you can use HTTP Delivery.

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.payments#http-delivery